# How to make regular expressions for Smilyes iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have tried the above code in my case it wont work please help me, I want to replace smileys for [$-1]....[$-9], [$-a]...[$-g]

For example for the string `"This is my Smilyes [$-1] it looks beautiful [$-a] The Value"`, it should replace with 2 smileys in replace with `[$-1]` and `[$-a]` result should be like this `"This is my Smilyes (@ Smiley) it looks beautiful (@ Smiley) The Value"`

We use below code for this

```
NSString *formattedText = @"This is my Smilyes [$-1] it looks beautiful [$-a] The Value"; NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\[\$\-1\])|(\[\$\-2\])|(\[\$\-3\])|(\[\$\-4\])|(\[\$\-5\])|(\[\$\-6\])|(\[\$\-7\])|(\[\$\-8\])|(\[\$\-9\])|(\[\$\-a\])|(\[\$\-b\])|(\[\$\-c\])|(\[\$\-d\])|(\[\$\-e\])|(\[\$\-f\])|(\[\$\-g\])" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:formattedText
                                  options:kNilOptions
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, formattedText.length)];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:formattedText];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches)
{

    NSString *match = [formattedText substringWithRange:result.range];
    NSTextAttachment *imageAttachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
    imageAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", match]];
    NSAttributedString *replacementForTemplate = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:imageAttachment];
    [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:result.range
                          withAttributedString:replacementForTemplate];

    NSLog(@"Matches are = %@",match);
}

[_textView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Matches are correct which are [$-1] and [$-a]

But output is like this This is my Smilyes (@ Smiley) it looks beautiful [$-a(@ Smiley) Value

I am wonder where is the issue if matches are fine then why it won't replace exact matches it just replace "[$-1]" with smiley and "] The" with Smiley

Comment: try this `@"\[\$-[123456789abcdefg]\]"`

Comment: Not resolved issue is same , just replace first [$-1] with smileys but when i add more than one codes for smileys it just replace smiley from 5th character which is "]" and replace four more characters after this "]"